# Angular. Как получить значение с input представления в компонент?

Tags: angular

component.html

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
<div class="form-group">
      <label for="passwordInput">Пароль</label>
      <input type="password" id="passwordInput" class="form-control" placeholder="Введите пароль" [(ngModel)]="password">
</div>
...
</form>
```

component.ts

```
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {

...

  password: string;

  onSubmit(){

    if (this.checkIsEmpty(this.password)){
      this.emptyLoginError = true;
      console.log("Введён пустой пароль");
    }

}
```

password всегде underfined

Comment: используйте реактивные формы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавь name Пример:

```
<input type="password" id="passwordInput" class="form-control" name="someName" placeholder="Введите пароль" [(ngModel)]="password">
```

или [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" Пример:

```
<input type="password" id="passwordInput" class="form-control" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" placeholder="Введите пароль" [(ngModel)]="password">
```